# How to return all rows on left except if item exists on right but doesn't match

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two tables, as below:

Table A

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Item 1 |
| 2 | Item 2 |
| 3 | Item 3 |

Table B

| id | id_from_tableA | External ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | abcd |
| 2 | 2 | efgh |

I would like to return all rows from `Table A`, unless they don't exist in `Table B` or *do* exist but doesn't match on both `id_from_tableA` and `External ID`

So, using the tables above, and a given External ID of `ijkl` I'd like to return

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Item 1 |
| 3 | Item 3 |

`Item 1` and `Item 3` return as they don't exist in `Table B`.

`Item 2` *doesn't* return as there's no match in `Table B`.

The system is a block list of sorts. Show everything unless there's a permission on it that doesn't match.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrasing this along the lines of your exact description, I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE b.id_from_tableA = a.id) OR
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b
                  WHERE b.id_from_tableA = a.id AND b.external_id = 'ijkl');
```

This logic says to retain any A record which does not appear in the B table at all, or does appear, but with External ID of `ijkl`.

Comment: You can do this with a single NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 1):

**You can actually do this with a single `NOT EXISTS` check:**

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE b.id_from_tableA = a.id AND b.external_id <> 'ijkl'
);
```

So if there are *no* matches against `id` at all then it `NOT EXIST` returns true. If there is a match but the `external_id` is the same then it also returns true. It only returns false if a *different* `external_id` is there.

Comment: I was just pointing it out to you because I thought you missed it. I wasn't trying to be malicious, just trying to give the best answer for OP. If it so sorely hurts you that you think a comment on a different answer needs a downvote on this one then I don't know what to say. One should vote on the merit of the answer, not on the actions of the answerer.

Comment: Well for my eyes, this answer is better.

Comment: @Charlieface That does indeed work, thanks man! Not sure who downvoted you, I'm not even sure why this question was edited. StackOverflow is a strange beast at times. Thanks for your help!